How to run a thread group parallel to other 3 thread groups (run sequentially)
I need to run 4 APIs in a script. 1 API is independent and rest 3 should run in sequential as there are some extractors are being used. All 4 APIs needs to run with different throughput values i.e
API 1 : 2600 req/min
API 2 : 15000 req/min
API 3 : 60 req/min
API 4 : 1 req/min

I started using using a single thread group for this and used 4 different 'Constant throughput timer' under each sampler. But that didn't worked. I read one of the article which said that we have to use different thread groups to use the multiple 'constant throughput timer'. So I have defined each API in different thread group now each having a constant throughput timer.
But first API (first thread group) has to run in parallel with other 3 (these 3 APIs/threadGroups needs to run sequentially).
I checked 'Run Thread group consecutively' option in test plan but it will run all 4 in parallel. Can someone help me to achieve the requirement !
Thanks in advance !

You can use either __setProperty() and __P() functions along with If Controller or Inter-Thread Communication Plugin for passing data between Thread Groups.
More information: Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups
As of JMeter 5.6.3 (latest as of now) the described Thread Groups behaviour is not possible.
